# Simple way to evaluate $f(n)= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}r^n x^r$

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, stirling-numbers, polylogarithm

Does anyone know a simpler formula than the one below for calculating values of this function for any positive integer n?

$$f(n)= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}r^n x^r$$
Here's the derivation for the best formulae I could come up with:
$$ \frac {1}{1-x} = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} x^r$$
Differentiating n times:
$$ \frac {n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}} = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}(r+1)(r+2)...(r+n) x^r=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac 1r r^{(n+1)} x^r$$
Where $r^{(n)}$denots rising factorial. Expanding rising factorial in terms of Unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind:
$$ \frac {n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}} = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac 1r \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}c(n+1,k)r^kx^r=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}c(n+1,k+1)r^kx^r \\ \therefore \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}c(n+1,n+1)r^nx^r=\frac {n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}-\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c(n+1,k+1)r^kx^r $$
Since $c(n+1,n+1)=1$, $$ f(n)=\frac {n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c(n+1,k+1)f(k)$$ This is a recurrence relation with $f(0)=\frac {1}{1-x}$ and thus should be solvable but I don't have the skill to do so.

Also, this function can be represented as a polylogarithm and this leads to a closed-form but still complicated solution in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind:
$$f(n)=Li_{-n}(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+r}S(n+1,r+1)\frac{r!}{(1-x)^{r+1}}$$

Any help solving the recurrence or exploiting properties of the polylogarithm would be very much appreciated.

ALSO solving the recurrence would lead to a relation between Stirling numbers of the first and second kinds and a different representation of the polylogarithm.

Comment: It is probably easier to take the derivative once, then multiply by $x$, then take the derivative again, and multiply by $x$, etc.  At least for a known $n$, IMO

Comment: Ha, believe me, trying to solve a recurrence relation that has a function in terms of the sum of itself is no normal recurrence relation.  I expect that most of what you wish to find lies under polylogarithm.

Comment: Yeah, beginning to see that. If it were a simple linear recurrence of 5 or 6 or 40 terms it would be fine, but it's in n terms...

Comment: Your function should be of two variables, $x$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach is as follows:
Let
$$
S(t) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty e^{rt}x^r = \sum_{r=0}^\infty (e^t x)^r = \frac{1}{1-e^t x},
$$
for sufficiently small $x$. Then
$$
S^{(n)}(t) = \frac{\partial^n}{\partial t^n} \left[ \frac{1}{1-e^t x} \right] = \frac{e^t x}{(1-e^t x)^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A(n,k+1) (e^t x)^k,
$$
where $A(n,k+1)$ are the Eulerian numbers. Now, set $t=0$ to obtain
$$
S^{(n)}(0) = f(n) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty r^n x^r = \frac{x}{(1-x)^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A(n,k+1) x^k = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A(n,k+1) x^{n-k}.
$$

I don't know if this should be considered 'simpler' than your formula, but at least it rids you of recurrences and infinite sums.

Comment: Thanks! The Eulerian numbers are a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this counts as an answer, and maybe you know this already, but here is what I think is a simpler recurrence relation:

$$f(n)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1-x},& \text{if }n=0,
\\\\ \frac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \,f(k),& \text{if } n\ge 1.
\\\\
\end{cases}$$

I haven't thought through the convergence issues here carefully, but I think this is good for $\,\vert x \vert \lt 1.$

Proving the recurrence relation for $n \ge 1$ is a straightforward application of the binomial theorem.

\begin{align}
\frac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \,f(k)
&= \frac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \sum_{r=0}^\infty r^k x^r
\\\\&=\frac{x}{1-x} \sum_{r=0}^\infty  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} r^k \cdot x^r
\\\\&= \frac{x}{1-x} \sum_{r=0}^\infty \left((r+1)^n-r^n \right)x^r
\\\\&= \frac{x}{1-x} \left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty (r+1)^n x^r - \sum_{r=0}^\infty r^n x^r\right)
\\\\&= \frac{x}{1-x} \left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty r^n x^{r-1} - \sum_{r=0}^\infty r^n x^r\right)
\\\\&=\frac{x}{1-x}  \sum_{r=0}^\infty r^n x^{r-1} (1-x)
\\\\&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty r^n x^r
\\\\&=f(n).
\end{align}

---

I don't know if it would be useful or not, but I'll throw in another formula here that might come in handy:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n!} = \frac{1}{1-ex},$$

proved as follows:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n!}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{r^n x^r}{n!}
\\\\&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r^n}{n!} x^r
\\\\&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty e^r x^r
\\\\&=\frac{1}{1-ex}.
\end{align}

As before, I haven't really thought through the convergence issues, but I think this is valid for $\,\vert x \vert < 1/e.$

Comment: Hadn't tried that method exactly, but I believe it links back to the polylogarithm. There is a representation  for it in terms of successive derivatives of x/(1-x) and one in terms of binomials